Flutter: Scheduled notification on all devices
I develop a flutter app with firebase for iOS and Android. One feature of the app is that the user can set a reminder for a specific time or repeat interval and at that time a notification should appear. As the user can log in on multiple devices, the notification should appear on all devices. To achieve this, I was thinking about 2 options:
Option 1
Local notification: Send a Firebase Cloud Message (FCM) data message to all devices once a reminder is created on a device to notify other devices that they need to schedule a local notification as well.
Advantage: The notification is scheduled locally, which means it also appears when the device has not internet connection.
Disadvantage: Data messages are not reliable (at least on iOS) and they might not appear at all, especially if the device is sleeping, has low battery etc. This means the other device might never schedule a notification.
Option 2
Cloud Messages: Schedule periodic firebase cloud function every minute that checks if a reminder for a user is due by accessing their firestore data. If so, send a notification cloud message to all devices.
Advantage: Notification messages are reliable and appear immediately on all devices.
Disadvantage: If the device has no internet connection at that time, the notification does not appear at all.
Are there any other options or what is the proper way to achieve this?
